# How do I convert an SQL script into actual viewable data sets to include in my portfolio?

Tags: postgresql, datatables, sql-scripts

I am a complete newbie. Transitioning into data analytics. Currently at the stage of getting my hands dirty with portfolio projects to ensure I'm more marketable, hehe.

I completed one of these interactive guided projects. The problem is, the only data that was available to download was the SQL script for creating and inserting data into tables... As opposed to data sets in form of an excel file, i.e.

Now, I want to recreate the code again so it sticks, but I have no idea how to actually view these data sets that are created in the SQL script I could download. I would like to transform that script into actual, viewable tables. How do I do that?

I appreciate any help in advance and my apologies if this is dummy. I tried looking for answers beforehand.

Comment: Run your script against a database, then `SELECT *` from those tables?

Answer (score -2):

This is one of those questions where there is more than one answer but if you are comfortable with Excel you could import the data and have at it.  You will need to install the [PostgreSQL ODBC drivers](https://odbc.postgresql.org/).

With [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-power-query-in-excel-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a) (known as Get & Transform in Excel), you can import or connect to external data, and then shape that data, for example remove a column, change a data type, or merge tables, in ways that meet your needs. Then, you can load your query into Excel to create charts and reports.

I just found out that the latest versions of Office still include *Microsoft Query* (although it looks like it hasn't been updated in 25 years).  It's an old tool but using Microsoft Query, you can connect to external data sources, select data from those external sources, import that data into your worksheet, and refresh the data as needed to keep your worksheet data synchronized with the data in the external sources.

If you want an authentic mid-90s experience checkout: [Use Microsoft Query to retrieve external data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e)

Comment: Thanks! Although I didn't use one of the ways you suggested, you led me to figuring out the solution myself. I downloaded TablePlus and it was pretty easy from there!